# Redirect command and output to a file

Tags: command-line, redirect, cat

Commands executed:

```
    cat a1.txt | grep a | wc -l >> a.txt
    cat b.txt | grep a | wc -l >> a.txt
    cat c.txt | grep a | wc -l >> a.txt
```

I want count and the command to append to a.txt.

like

**Expected file output:** Assume 100,200,300 are counts.

```
cat a1.txt | grep a | wc -l  100
cat b.txt | grep a | wc -l 200
cat c.txt | grep a | wc -l  300
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Count how many times, 'a' appears in the file a.txt, and then output it back into a.txt?

Comment: @bc2946088 it's not like that. My aim is to store command and output as key value.

Comment: I haven't a clue what you're trying.  I don't know that anyone else will either.  Maybe adjust your question.

Comment: @bc2946088 Updated

Answer (score 0):

Either

1. use the [`script`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/script.1.html) command to capture the terminal, and then edit the results, or
2. store the command in a variable and then evaluate the command:

   ```
   cmd='cat a1.txt | grep a | wc -l'
   printf "%s\t%s\n" "$cmd" "$(eval "$cmd")" >> a.txt
   ```

   Generalizing this:

   ```
   print_and_do() { local cmd="$1"; printf "%s\t%s\n" "$cmd" "$(eval "$cmd")"; }
   {
       print_and_do "cat a1.txt | grep a | wc -l"
       print_and_do "cat b.txt | grep a | wc -l"
       print_and_do "cat c.txt | grep a | wc -l"
   } >> a.txt
   ```

Are you aware that `cat a1.txt | grep a | wc -l` can be written as:

```
grep -c a a1.txt
```

Comment: I know that. I am looking for other hadoop commands. For an eg, i have given this.